# How to Remove world write permissions in Linux

Tags: linux

I got this vulnerability report where it says I `Remove world write permissions`.

So I tried to find the files with `write` permissions using the below command:

```
find / -perm -0002 -type f
```

And my output looks like below (I have removed most of the output, **but all these outputs are for the two directories `/proc` and `/sys`**

```
...
/proc/235399/attr/fscreate
/proc/235399/attr/keycreate
/proc/235399/attr/sockcreate
/proc/235399/timerslack_ns
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-904374614.slice/user@904374614.service/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-904374614.slice/user-runtime-dir@904374614.service/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-904374614.slice/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-904374614.slice/session-5.scope/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/init.scope/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/rngd.service/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/irqbalance.service/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/systemd-update-utmp.service/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice/systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B055\x2dF6D2.service/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/var-log.mount/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/systemd-udevd-control.socket/cgroup.event_control
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/lvm2-monitor.service/cgroup.event_control
...
```

My question is, is it a good practice to remove the `writable` permissions for these files? Doesn't it going to affect any running programs to fail?

Answer (score 0):

It's completely useless to remove those permissions. `/proc` and `/sys` are not permanent filesystems, after the next reboot they are going to be the same again.

Comment: Are there any paths I should AVOID like this?

Comment: run `mount`. Basically everything that's not a *real* filesystem for storage.

Comment: So anything that comes out in `mount` can be neglected?

Answer (score 0):

These are files on kernel pseudo-filesystems (procfs and sysfs) which control different kernel behaviors.

The command to use is `chmod o-w <filename>` but I doubt it would work for the above-mentioned files. And even if it worked - in this specific case it may negatively affect your system stability.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you tell me what kind of other paths I should AVOID like this?

Comment: `/dev` for sure. But in most cases Linux distros are properly configured in this regard. You should only be concerned with permissions of your own files which in 99% of the cases should be in your home directory.

Comment: I used the command `find / -perm -o+w` and now I get a different hit for the `/opt` and `/tmp` directories as well. They seem to be symlinks... Should I worry about these too?

Comment: You didn't say what distro you have, I am on `rpm` based one and it allows you to verify installed files by running `rpm -Va` (as root). Anything with `M` in second column indicates file mode (permissions) was modified since install. I cannot say for sure about `/opt`, for `/tmp` - it depends. It holds temporary files (and sometimes sockets and pipes) and in some cases they need to be world writable. But regular temporary files owned by you which are world writable are a bit suspicious and may require closer look.

Comment: I have the following: `NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.5 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.5"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 (Ootpa)"`

Comment: Then you can use `rpm` to check for altered files. But please take it with a bit grain of salt, some files WILL change as you configure your system to suit your needs.